# Increment string from given array of letters or exclude specific letters from incremental with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, increment

I have a list of allowed letters

```
$allowedLetters = array('B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','R','S','T','V','W','X','Y','Z');
```

And from that array I would like to do string increment to get the following pattern:

```
BBB, BBC, BBD ... until ZZZ
```

I know that I can do string increment as simple as this:

```
$letters = array();
$letter = 'BBB';
while ($letter !== 'ZZZ') {    
    $letters[] = $letter++;    
}

print_r($letters);
```

But it will not match my allowed letters list, and I just can not find a way how to either do an increment using allowed list or just exclude letters that I do not want such as:

```
A,E,I,O,Q,U
```

**What could be more simple?** I would appreciate if anyone could assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a solution starting from your code that involves [`strcspn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php) function:

```php
$letters = array();
$letter = 'BBB';
while ($letter !== 'ZZZ') {
    $letter++;  
    if(strcspn($letter, "AEIOU") == 3 )       
        $letters[] = $letter;    
}

print_r($letters);
```

The mentioned function returns the index of the first occurrence of the characters listed in `needle` parameter. So, in our case, it will return a value in the range `[0-2]` if any of the characters is present. According to the manual page, no one of the characters specified in `needle` list is found, the length of the original string is returned (in our scenario it is always equal to 3).

This means that making sure that it returns 3 we are accepting only strings that don't contain the forbidden characters `"AEIOU"`, appending them to our output array.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not an expert but this looks very elegant and simple. I will be happy to accept the answer if nobody else wants to add something. Hope this can be useful to anyone else. Appreciate your help!!!!